# How to set attribute with angularjs without html encoding

Tags: angularjs

I need to set a title attribute of an HTML element using angularjs.
The variable contains a "&" character. This character is encoded (or "sanitized") by angularjs.

Here is an example:

```html
ng-attr-title="{{mymessage}}"

mymessage = "First line.&#13;Second Line"
```

The result is :

```html
"First line.&amp;#13;Second Line"
```

The desired result is :

```html
"First line.&#13;Second Line"
```

How can I achieve this result using angularjs ?

EDIT:

I need to add custom text inside a TITLE attribute, like this:

```html
<img src="tooltip.png" title="{{myMessageWithSpecialCharacyers}}" />
```

Comment: Try `ng-bind-html` or `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

Comment: But is possible with ng-bind-html to set an attribute inside a HTML tag ?

Comment: I think you'd have to [disable $sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#can-i-disable-sce-completely-) to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you: Did you try putting the text in  ng-bind-html?

See [$sanitize documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) at the bottom